# Custom JSF Control isn't binding properly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

So I have been asked to make a custom JSF control that will handle results paging for my company's website. For this component, three of the four methods to the backing bean work properly, but the last one isn't working. Maybe I'm missing something, but the code looks correct. I was hoping the community could shed some light on what is going on.

So here's the code. It's `#{cc.attrs.goToLastPage}` that is misbehaving

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="showingRecordMin" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="showingRecordMax" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="totalRecords" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="resultsPerPage" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="currentPageNum" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="totalPagesNum" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="resultsPerPageItems" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="resultPagesItems" required="true" />

    <cc:attribute name="goToNextPage" 
        method-signature="java.lang.String action()" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="goToPreviousPage"
        method-signature="java.lang.String action()" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="goToFirstPage"
        method-signature="java.lang.String action()" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="goToLastPage"
        method-signtature="java.lang.String action()" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- Question: We can't have a form inside of a form. Do we ecapsulate form operations here or 
    should the client handle them? -->
<cc:implementation>
    <div
        style="background-color: #F0F3FA; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 2px 8px; position: relative; vertical-align: middle;">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <div style="float: left; width: auto;">
                Showing Results <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.showingRecordMin}" />  - <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.showingRecordMax}" /> of
                #{cc.attrs.totalRecords} Results per Page:
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{cc.attrs.resultsPerPage}" onchange="$j(document).find('.pageBarSubmitBtn').click();">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.resultsPerPageItems}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </div>
            <div style="float: right; width: auto;">
                Showing Page #{cc.attrs.currentPageNum} of #{cc.attrs.totalPagesNum} Jump
                to Page
                <h:selectOneMenu id="_pagesMenu" value="#{cc.attrs.currentPage}" onchange="$j(document).find('.pageBarSubmitBtn').click();">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.resultPagesItems}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <!-- These three work properly -->
                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{cc.attrs.goToFirstPage}"> 
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-first.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{cc.attrs.goToPreviousPage}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-previous.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{cc.attrs.goToNextPage}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-next.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <!-- This one is the bad guy -->
                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{cc.attrs.goToLastPage}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-last.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>

            </div>
            <h:commandButton style="visibility: hidden;" styleClass="jsfHidden pageBarSubmitBtn"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

Going on, here is the exception that gets thrown out of the console

```
09:23:15,108 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-localhost-  127.0.0.1-3333-5) Unable to resolve composite component from using page using EL expression '#  {cc.attrs.goToLastPage}': javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to resolve composite component from   using page using EL expression '#{cc.attrs.goToLastPage}'
```

Here is how the control is used in my page:
     syntax

Finally here is the interface that my backing bean is implementing to use with this control

```
public interface PagableResults {
    public int getShowingRecordMin();
    public int getShowingRecordMax();

    public ResultsPerPage getResultsPerPage();
    public void setResultsPerPage(ResultsPerPage rpp);

    public int getCurrentPageNum();
    public void setCurrentPageNum(int pageNum);

    public int getTotalPagesNum();
    public int getTotalRecordsNum();

    public List<SelectItem> getResultsPerPageItems();
    public List<SelectItem> getResultsPagesItems();

    public void goToFirstPage();
    public void goToLastPage();
    public void goToPreviousPage();
    public void goToNextPage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled method-signature:

```
<cc:attribute name="goToLastPage"
    method-signtature="java.lang.String action()" required="true"/>
```

Comment: Great Job! I have been staring at the code for hours and never noticed that! I guess the eye sees only what it wants to see!